# Simple parallel multiprocessing for defined function with multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I know there are plenty of examples for this question but I wish to know the very basic of the idea how to run multiprocessing with multiple arguments with for a simple defined functions as the code example below. This function takes three arguments from three indepedent lists with number and output a single number 1800.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
list3 = [11,12,13,14,15]

def somefunc(x, y, z):
        out = 0
        for i in range(len(x)):
                num = x[i] * y[i] * z[i]
                out = out + num
        return(out)

somefunc(list1,list2,list3)
```

I wish to apply `pool` and `map` from `multiprocessing` to execute it in parallel. My idea is to apply something like the below:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
p = mp.Pool(4)
output = p.map(somefunc, <PARAMETERS "x, y, z">, <ITERATION "i">))
p.close()
```

I believe that there are better approaches and I appreciate it. However, my intention for this post is that I really wish to know if this is doable. If it is doable, how can it be done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is very much doable. Your approach is good and will do fine. You can also try using threads if you have a multi core machine. In multiprocessing, multiple processes are are used whereas in multi threading multiple threads are spawned. I think that your problem is simple enough to be handled by threads. So you can opt for threads.

Reply to comment : 
If you want to use Pool.map, then you'll have do some changes in your code.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [6,7,8,9,10] 
list3 = [11,12,13,14,15]

def somefunc(list):
    x = list[0]
    y = list[1]
    z = list[2]
    out = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
            num = x[i] * y[i] * z[i]
            out = out + num
    return(out)

import multiprocessing as mp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = mp.Pool(4)
    output = p.map(somefunc, [[list1, list2, list3]])
    p.close()
    print(output)
```

It is important to keep the line 
    `if __name__ == '__main__'` 
otherwise your process will freeze

Comment: How do I write the correct line? I have tried `p.map(somefunc, list1, list2, list3)` and `p.map(somefunc, list1, list2, list3, i)` but both don't work.